# javascript regex matching string conditions including special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate some strings.

**Rules:**
String can be contain A-Z, 0-9, "_", "!", ":".

If string contains 2x special characters, eg, "__" or "!!" or "K:KD:E" must return false.

**Examples**

Legitimate matches

```
FX:EURUSD
FX_IDC:XAGUSD
NYMEX_EOD:NG1!
```

Invalid matches:

```
0-BITSTAMP:BTCUSD - contains a  minus sign)
2.5*AMEX:VXX+AMEX:SVXY  - contains a *, a + and 2x ":"
AMEX:SPY/INDEX:VIX - contains a /
```

Comment: So what have you attempted?

Comment: /^[*()_+\-=\[\]{};'"\\|,.<>\/?]*$/.text(str)

Comment: Try out your own regex using an online tool like [this](https://regex101.com/#pcre)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
/^(?:[A-Z0-9]|([_!:])(?!.*\1))+$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW9iZ5/1)

`([_!:])(?!.*\1)` will ensure there is no repetition of special characters.

Answer (score 0):

I would first start out with regex to remove all strings containing invalid characters:

```
/[^A-Z0-9_!:]/
```

I would then use this to check for duplicates:

```
/(_.*_)|(!.*!)|(:.*:)/
```

These can be combined to give:

```
/([^A-Z0-9_!:])|(_.*_)|(!.*!)|(:.*:)/
```

This can be seen in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/nP3tV9/1).

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/JosephGarrone/Lv902rd6/1/) is a JSFiddle showing it working.

Answer (score 0):

I eventrually used pattern

```
var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z_!0-9]+:?[a-zA-Z_!0-9]+$/;
```